# Is there a way to echo a dropdfown value after selecting (clicking on) it?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code: ($uweeks is an array of numbers)

```
<form action = "" method = "post"> 
<select name="weekdrop"><option value="Weeks">Choose a Week</option>
<?php                 
  for($x=0; $x < $uwsize; $x++)   {
  echo "<option value= ". $uweeks[$x] ." >" . $uweeks[$x] . "</option>";
  }?>

 </select>
</form>
```

What I want to do is when someone choose one of the numbers in the drop down, to echo the number on that same page.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not in PHP - you'll have to use JavaScript. Do you know JavaScript at all?

Comment: I can learn it.  Well this was just for testing purposes, ultimately I just need the selected value stored in a variable somewhere for future uses.  I guess I'll use get/post.

Comment: changed tag from php to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `<select/>` tag to this:

```
<select name="weekdrop" onchange="document.getElementById('special_area').innerHTML = this.value">
```

Then print this where you want the text to appear:

```
<div id="special_area"></div>
```

That's how you can do it using JavaScript (along with PHP to produce your content). All dynamic changes for which you do not want to require the user to make a complete page reload, require JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. Not enough reputation to Vote Up :(

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like in these lines:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
       function customFun(colors) {
          var col = (colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].value);
          document.getElementById("selectedItem").innerHtml = "Selected color = " + col; 
       } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="colors" onChange="customFun(this)">
      <option value="white" selected>White</option>
      <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
      <option value="ivory">Ivory</option>
    </select>
    <div id="selectedItem"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```